# Split last two set of id's from string

Tags: java

I have the following string

```
ford-focus-albany-ny-v12356-l12205
```

I'm trying to parse the last two sets of numbers out

`12356` and `12205`

I'm using the prefix letter to define the id type since the order of those int may very.

```
v = vehicle id "id length may very"
l = location id "id length may very"
```

I'd also like to add one may exist without the other. Example

`ford-focus-v12356` or `albany-ny-l12205`

I'm really not sure what the best approach to splitting the string dynamically is, my initial thought was to find the last two - and then try to parse the ints from the prefix. Anybody have any suggestions or a possible example?

Comment: If both IDs do exist, will they always come in the same order (`v` then `l`) or could the order vary as well?

Comment: I would use a String.split ("-"); and go from there.

Comment: They will always come in the same order

Comment: If you define the rules of your string REGEX is the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "ford-focus-albany-ny-v12356-l12205";
    String[] substrings = str.split("-");
    for (String arg: substrings) {
        if (arg.matches("v[0-9]*")) {
            String v = arg.substring(1);
        }
        else if (arg.matches("l[0-9]*")) {
            String l = arg.substring(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as the best answer since it not only gives me the results I'm looking for, but also guarantees the groups to be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with regex expression and replace like this:

```
//this will give you 12356
"ford-focus-albany-ny-v12356-l12205".replaceAll( "(.*)(-v)([^-]*)(.*)", "$3" );

//this will give you 12205
"ford-focus-albany-ny-v12356-l12205".replaceAll( "(.*)(-l)([^-]*)(.*)", "$3" );

//this will also give you 12356
"ford-focus-v12356".replaceAll( "(.*)(-v)([^-]*)(.*)", "$3" ); 

//this will give you 12205
"albany-ny-l12205".replaceAll( "(.*)(-l)([^-]*)(.*)", "$3" );
```

Comment: Looks like the only problem with this code is when one of the values is missing if returns the entire string.

Comment: So, you should explain it on your question, then I will fix the code. As you said on the comments: 'They will always come in the same order'

Comment: That's correct they will always come in the same order, but unfortunately I don't always know that they are both going to be there. It's a url string, so they can exist independently.

Comment: The expression works for both or just one of then you just have to use one expression for the -v `(.*)(-v)([^-]*)(.*)` and the other for the -l `(.*)(-l)([^-]*)(.*)` the four examples was just to show it working for both or just one of then.

Answer (score 1):

You can match one or both of them with a simple pattern:

```
(?:-([vl])(\\d+))(?:-[vl](\\d+))?
```

The idea behind this pattern is simple: it matches and captures the initial marker `-v` or `-l`, followed by a sequence of digits, which are captured into capturing groups.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:-([vl])(\\d+))(?:-[vl](\\d+))?");
for(String s : new String[] {"ford-focus-albany-ny-v12356-l12205","ford-focus-albany-ny-l12205","ford-focus-albany-ny-v12356"}) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1).equals("v")) {
            System.out.println("verhicle="+m.group(2));
            String loc = m.group(3);
            if (loc != null) {
                System.out.println("location="+loc);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No location");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No vehicle");
            System.out.println("location="+m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/mRmHwl).

Comment: Would there be any issue if lets say one of the "non relevant" key words in the string contain -l? I can't think of an example right now, but perhaps some vehicle model like lexus-l300-v1234-l12205? I'm just trying to be sure I don't encounter a rare case.

Comment: Yes it would. Unfortunately. Also my expression will not face this problem just because the value you want is on the last position since I specified `(.*)(-l)` it will get everithing until the last -l. But this expression that @dasblinkenlight give to you is far more elegant then my own. So maybe he can fix this problem

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks, dasblinkenlight seems as if he's able to handle an absent value a little bit better. What would it take to be sure his regex is looking for the last group? I guess I'll just have to deal with any other risk that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to split with `String.split("-")` and then use the Array returned like this:

```
String[] result = longString.split("-");
// Get the last number
String lastPrefix = result[result.lenght-1].subString(0, 1);
// Here check the prefix
// try to get number
int lastNumber;
try {
    lastNumber =  = Integer.parseInt(result[result.lenght-1].subString(1));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Do something with exception
}

// And now do similar with result.lenght-2
```